# Dynamically setting the state is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set an array dynamically and render it using useState hook. But it seems the array is not setting. below is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default ({ item }) => {
    const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState([]);
    const setAttachmentValues = function(response){
        setAttachments(response.data);
        
    }
    const fetchMedia = async ()=> {
        setAttachments([]);           
        await apiCall().then((response) => {                
            setAttachmentValues(response);                
        });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMedia();
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
           <div className="w-full">
                {(attachments.map((ele) => {
                      <div>{ele}</div>
                )} 
        </>
    )
}
```

`apiCall()` will return an array of objects.

setState in this way is working well in some cases. What is the actual issue here?

Comment: Can you share more info about where it fails?
I don't think there is any issue with the code.
if the issue persists then do deep clone the response 
setAttachments([...response.data]);

Comment: Thank you so much, deep cloning resolved the issue @SyedAmanAli

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331693/dynamically-setting-the-state-is-not-working-in-react#comment132925358_75331693) `[...response.data]` is a _shallow copy_ of the array's elements, not a _deep clone_.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can render data

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default ({ item }) => {
  const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setAttachments(response);
        console.log(response);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
       <div>
        {attachments.map(item => <div key={item.username}> {item.username} </div> )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```